# Multi column lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, where-clause

Upon completeing the tutorial here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

I currently use the following

```
userAccesses = userAccesses.Where(s => s.employeeDetail.employeeNumber.ToUpper().Contains(searchValue.ToUpper()));
```

However I'd like to concatenate the knownas / surname columns and then do the contains on the concatenated items.

Could anyone explain/suggest an example syntax?

This is what I've attempted below but I'm certain my syntax is incorrect.

```
userAccesses = userAccesses.Where(s => s.employeeDetail.employeeNumber + " " + s.employeeDetail.knownas + " " + s.employeeDetail.surname).Contains(searchValue);
```

Thanks for the response everyone, final working version is below.

```
userAccesses.Where(x => (x.employeeDetail.employeeNumber + x.employeeDetail.knownas + x.employeeDetail.surname).Contains(searchValue));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go to this direction

```
public class Employee
{
    public string knownas { get; set; }

    public string userName { get; set; }
}
public void Test()
{
    List<Employee> employess = new List<Employee>();
    string searchvalue = "test";

    var listEmplyer = employess.Where(x => (x.userName + x.knownas).Contains(searchvalue));
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for your response, Once I saw the line below I was able to use this to correct my code.

employess.Where(x => (x.userName + x.knownas).Contains(searchvalue));

Comment: you are welcome, i try to give the path to follow, not exactly the code to write ^^

Answer (score 1):

You'll simply need to concatenate the string and call Contains on that string.

```
userAccesses
  .Where(s => $"{s.employeeDetail.employeeNumber} {s.employeeDetail.knownas} {s.employeeDetail.surname}".Contains(searchValue))
```

If you need an enumerable of strings as the result of the expression, you can also choose to use the following:

```
userAccesses
  .Select(s => $"{s.employeeDetail.employeeNumber} {s.employeeDetail.knownas} {s.employeeDetail.surname}")
  .Where(s => s.Contains(searchValue))
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, unfortunately this came back with an error for me. 

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Format(System.String, System.Object, System.Object, System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Answer (score 0):

Searching through concatenated column values is weird...

I'd suggest smth like this:

```
var filtered = userAccesses.Where(s => s.employeeDetail.employeeNumber.Contains(searchValue)
                                       || s.employeeDetail.knownas.Contains(searchValue)
                                       || s.employeeDetail.surname.Contains(searchValue));
```